# How to get every n-th data from database

Tags: mysql, sql

maybe someone can help me with this problem:

i have a huge amount of data in a database. Now i need to show them in a line chart.
At the moment i get every data so the chart looks terrible....

The question is:

how can I get only every n-th data ?
Any SQL Query suggestions?

Comment: Do your rows get entered in fixed intervals (say one per minute or second)?If not: Does your table have a timestamp / datetime column? Then the best approch may be not to take each nth row, but look at time ranges, e.g. ten minutes and take each last record in such range. So it wouldn't matter if you got many data at one time and fewer another and the line chart would be more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Every nth data point is a bit tricky.  In the most recent versions of MySQL, you can use `row_number()`.  Let me assume you have an older version.  Let me also assume that you have a sequential row id of some sort, so the question makes sense.

Then you can use variables to enumerate the rows:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from (select t.* from t order by id) t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) t
where mod(rn, <n>) = 1;
```